# Braintree Paypal Transaction Processor Declined (Invalid Currency Code)

Tags: paypal, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I am using Braintree as a payment gateway for website subscription for INR.
I created Merchant Account for INR currency, but transactions are being failed.
Transaction Status: Processor Declined.
Processor Response Text: Invalid Currency Code.

Not sure why this is happening even USD transactions are working.
I am using braintree_php library for braintree integration at the moment.
For more information, I associated US business paypal account to braintree.

Comment: Where can you read Processor Response Text?? I am also having trouble with this one

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/reference/currency-codes/ , footnote [3] , only Indian PayPal accounts can send and receive money in INR

Testing with a US account will result in an invalid currency error.

Comment: even I setup a Merchant Account?

Comment: Then where can I specify the currency code if my customers are from different countries?